# Javascript function to check for missing dates on JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, date, chart.js

I am in my rookie stage learning javascript. I made an API that gets a number of users registered on a certain date and returns this data as a JSON object. Here is a sample of that data

```
{"myjsonobject": [{"users": 3, "joined": "2013-05-25"}, {"users": 1, "joined": "2013-05-26"}, {"users": 1, "joined": "2013-05-30"}, {"users": 1, "joined": "2013-05-31"}]}
```

I then parse the data and graph on [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org) linegraph using the javascript function below

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
url = "http://mylink/getjson/"
Create_jsonObject(url)
});

function Create_jsonObject(url) {
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

myJSONObject=data;
var dataSource=myJSONObject.myjsonoject;
var chart = $("#chartContainer").dxChart({

    dataSource: dataSource,

    commonSeriesSettings: {

         argumentField: 'joined'

    },

    series: [

        { valueField: 'users', name: 'users' },

    ],

    argumentAxis:{

        grid:{

            visible: true

        }

    },

    tooltip:{

        enabled: true

     },

     title: 'Volunteer Registration',

     legend: {

        verticalAlignment: 'bottom',

        horizontalAlignment: 'center'

     },

    commonPaneSettings: {

        border:{

            visible: true,

            right: false

        }       

    }

 });


});
};
```

The function works in charting the JSON data on the linegraph. I would like to incorporate a javascript function that checks for missing dates and inserts 0 users where a date is missing. Thus the graph will plot zero where not date was returned. It should check this against the earliest date returned. Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Comment: so you want this to return false {"myjsonobject": [{"users": 3]} , but not this {"myjsonobject": [{"users": 3, "joined": "2013-05-25"}, {"users": 3}]} ?

Comment: Why not make json at server side only with missing date logic and provide it to Charts API. Why doing extra work at client side?

Comment: No. I would like the JSON object to remain as it is but in the event a date is missing, it should append a 0. For example {"myjsonobject": [{"users": 3, "joined": "2013-05-25"},{"users": 0,  "joined": "2013-05-26"}, {"users": 2,  "joined": "2013-05-27"}]}

Comment: @amrinder007 I would like to do this on the client side because the data would be spaced out according to date. It would make a slow API if it returns all those null values. Should we have data spaced out between months, there would be many null values thus slowing down the API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to fill in missing elements in an array describing a range

Presuming the starting array is already sorted, you might want to copy the first element in the source array into a new one and then iteratively push "default objects" into the destination array or copy from the source array when there is a matching object. Repeat until you reach the end of your range.

To check if there is a matching object, you might want to index first the source array by whatever parameter you want to iterate over (in your case: the "joined" field). This means that this parameter has to be unique.

```
function getIndex(srcArray, field) {
    var i, l, index;
    index = [];
    for(i = 0, l = srcArray.length; i < l; i++) {
        index[srcArray[i][field]] = srcArray[i];
    }
    return index;
}
```

This creates a hashmap of your array. Searching an element by it's key (in your case the "joined" field) is very simple:

```
if(index['2013-06-05'] !== undefined) { 
    /* the element indexed by "2013-06-05" exists */ 
}
```

Now that you have an index, you can iterate over the range you expect to have. For this, get the first and the last dates in your source array:

```
//get boundaries
var first = new Date(src[0].joined);
var last = new Date(src[src.length-1].joined);
```

You also need to know how to construct your default objects:

```
function createDefault(datestr) {
    return {users: 0, joined: datestr};
}
```

Now declare a destination array and iterate over the range:

```
var dest = [];
for(var d = first; d.getTime() <= last.getTime(); d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)) {
    datestr = dateToYMD(d); //dateToYMD is a helper function I declared that formats a date
    if(index[datestr]) {
        //this date exists in your data, copy it
        dest.push(index[datestr]);
    } else {
        //this date does not exist, create a default
        dest.push(createDefault(datestr));
    }
}
```

I made a jsfiddle that logs the destination array to console. 
http://jsfiddle.net/uNasR/

Comment: I know this is an old topic.... but this code does not include the last date in the output. `{"users": 1, "joined": "2013-05-31"}` is part of the json but the last outputed date it 05-30. If I add more dates, the final one is never included in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fixDate(data)
{
    var myObjects=JSON.parse(data);

    for(var i=0;i<myObjects.length;i++)
    {
      if(!myObjects[i].joined)
         myObjects[i].joined="0";

    }
    return myObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fix(json){ 
  var updateUserToDate = function(object){ 
    if (!object['joined']){ object.joined = 0 }
  }
  json.myjsonobject.forEach(updateUserToDate);
  return json;
}
```

this is my version of it

if your data is still in string format you will need to call JSON.parse on it before you send it to this function, as Ewald Stieger points out

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is a little confusion.

Based on code you provided, I think you are using THIS ChartJS:
http://chartjs.devexpress.com

:)

With that,I would try one more way to reach your goal: specify explicitely type of your arguments:

```
argumentAxis: {
    grid: {
        visible: true
    },
    //add this line to specify
    argumentType: "datetime"
},
```

More info [in ChartJS documentation](http://chartjs.devexpress.com/ApiReference/dxChart/Configuration/argumentAxis#argumentType)

Comment: Hi Andrey, Yes I am using Chartjs. Already there is a parse date function in the ChartJS javascript files that come with it. After following the methodology proposed by Roman, my code worked just as I expected it. Not sure what I will be trying to achive by adding that line. Please advice

Comment: There are two products with name "ChartJS" on the web. One is managed by independent developer, while another one is managed by DevExpress. You are definetely using second one, but reference you used pointed to the site of first product.


I supposed that you are still providing dates as strings, without usage of date parsing. Code which I provided would enable auto-parsing inside of dxChart itself, with no need to write custom code. That is the only difference.