# Fill missing dates in json string with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here's a sample of what I have:

```js
[{
  "probeTemp": "35.40",
  "dateProbe": "2015-08-1"
}, {
  "probeTemp": "34.89",
  "dateProbe": "2015-08-3"
}, {
  "probeTemp": "34.42",
  "dateProbe": "2015-08-5"
}]
```

How can I fill the missing dates between the min and max dates in the json string so the missing fields end up like this?

```js
    [{
      "probeTemp": "35.40",
      "dateProbe": "2015-08-1"
    }, {
      "probeTemp": null,
      "dateProbe": "2015-08-2"
    }, {
      "probeTemp": "34.89",
      "dateProbe": "2015-08-3"
    }, {
      "probeTemp": null,
      "dateProbe": "2015-08-4"
    }, {
      "probeTemp": "34.42",
      "dateProbe": "2015-08-5"
    }]
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956063/javascript-function-to-check-for-missing-dates-on-json-object), but I don't know how I could apply it to my data. Any help?

Edit 2: [This is what I tried so far](https://pastebin.com/tA3jMFg6), but I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` at lines 7 and 23.

Comment: What do you mean by missing dates ? Between min and max ?

Comment: @Weedoze Yes, sorry for not being specific. I will edit my question.

Comment: Have you tried something ? Get the min and max then iterate each day between theml

Comment: @Weedoze I started trying something, but my knowledge in javascript/jquery isn't very extensive. I managed to do it with mySQL, but I prefer to let the client handle this.

Comment: Why is `2015-08-3` duplicated ?

Answer (score 4):

We starts from getting first and last dates. Let

```
const a = [{
  "probeTemp": "35.40",
  "dateProbe": "2015-08-1"
}, {
  "probeTemp": "34.89",
  "dateProbe": "2015-08-3"
}, {
  "probeTemp": "34.42",
  "dateProbe": "2015-08-5"
}];
```

Then

```
const firstDate = a[0].dateProble; // "2015-08-1"
const lastDate = a[a.length-1].dateProbe; // "2015-08-5"
```

Now we can build range of all dates.

```
const dates = [ ...Array(
        Date.parse(lastDate)/86400000 - Date.parse(firstDate)/86400000 + 1).keys()    
    ].map(k => new Date(
            86400000*k+Date.parse(firstDate)
        ).toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-0(\d)$/, '-$1')); 
// [ "2015-08-1", "2015-08-2", "2015-08-3", "2015-08-4", "2015-08-5" ]
```

We created range with proper length, then moved it in timeline by number of milliseconds from epoch to first of dates. Finally we created Dates again transform
to strings, sliced to get more natural format of dates and use regexp to remove leading `0` from number of days.

In last step we can define `res` - variable that contain our results. We define it as empty array and in for loop pushing next elements. Most important is `probeTemp`. If date that we considering from our range is equal date from array then we can add `probeTemp` and then increment `j` index, if it is new date than `probeTemp` is equall null and `j` index is not changed.

```
let res = []; 
for(let i=0,j=0; i<dates.length; i++) { 
    res[i] = {
        dateProbe: dates[i], 
        probeTemp: dates[i] === a[j].dateProbe ? a[j++].probeTemp : null
    }; 
}; 
console.table(res);
```

This solution works for sorted array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i would do somethink like this.

1. Fetch the first Date and parse ist Date.parse()
2. walk to the next Date, check if the first date + 1 (new Date()getDate() + 1) is the same Date, if so walk next if not creating this Date and inserting it.
3. And so on

Comment: Do you mind giving me an example in code of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a Date using the api [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) which is smart enough to - when advanced a day at a time in an iteration - account for short months, leap years, etc. Advance by adding 1 to whatever the getDate() returns (on the Date instance) and then call the setDate method with that later value. Or add the number of milliseconds in a day using the getTime and setTime methods.

Check each date against your previously existing map of probe temperatures

You can have another instance of the max date lying in wait for comparison. Use the getTime method on both instances when doing your comparisons, ie:

```
if ( iterDate.getTime() !== maxDate.getTime() ) {
    if ( !previousProbeTemp )
        newProbeTemp = null;
```