# find the missing days from array of dates Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am getting an array of day dates from an API

The data is sorted and more than one date is skipped.

I have to create the daily, weekly, and monthly reports from the below data.
If there are any missing dates, then I have to add the missing dates into the array with the previous date's 'Workcompletion' value.

I found a similar question on here: [Find missing day from array of dates javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654656/find-missing-day-from-array-of-dates-javascript), but those answers don't handle the more than one day missing.

```
1: {Date: '2021-09-24T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
2: {Date: '2021-09-25T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
3: {Date: '2021-09-26T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
4: {Date: '2021-09-27T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
5: {Date: '2021-09-28T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
6: {Date: '2021-09-29T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
7: {Date: '2021-09-30T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
8: {Date: '2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
9: {Date: '2021-10-02T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
10: {Date: '2021-10-03T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
11: {Date: '2021-10-04T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
12: {Date: '2021-10-05T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
13: {Date: '2021-10-06T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
14: {Date: '2021-10-07T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
15: {Date: '2021-10-08T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
16: {Date: '2021-10-10T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
17: {Date: '2021-10-11T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
18: {Date: '2021-10-12T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
19: {Date: '2021-10-13T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 0}
20: {Date: '2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
21: {Date: '2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
22: {Date: '2021-10-16T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
23: {Date: '2021-10-17T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
24: {Date: '2021-10-18T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
25: {Date: '2021-10-19T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
26: {Date: '2021-10-20T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
27: {Date: '2021-10-21T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
28: {Date: '2021-10-22T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
29: {Date: '2021-10-23T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
30: {Date: '2021-10-24T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
31: {Date: '2021-10-25T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
32: {Date: '2021-10-26T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
33: {Date: '2021-10-27T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
34: {Date: '2021-10-28T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
35: {Date: '2021-10-29T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
36: {Date: '2021-10-30T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
37: {Date: '2021-10-31T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
38: {Date: '2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
39: {Date: '2021-11-02T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
40: {Date: '2021-11-03T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
41: {Date: '2021-11-04T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
42: {Date: '2021-11-05T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
43: {Date: '2021-11-07T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
44: {Date: '2021-11-08T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
45: {Date: '2021-11-09T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
46: {Date: '2021-11-10T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
47: {Date: '2021-11-11T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
48: {Date: '2021-11-12T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
49: {Date: '2021-11-13T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
50: {Date: '2021-11-14T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
51: {Date: '2021-11-15T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
52: {Date: '2021-11-16T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 1.35}
53: {Date: '2021-11-18T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 3.27}
54: {Date: '2021-11-21T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 10.87}
55: {Date: '2021-11-22T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 12.76}
56: {Date: '2021-11-28T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 19.5}
57: {Date: '2021-11-29T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 19.5}
58: {Date: '2021-11-30T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 19.5}
59: {Date: '2021-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 20.5}
60: {Date: '2021-12-02T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 21.49}
61: {Date: '2021-12-05T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 22.16}
62: {Date: '2021-12-06T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 22.16}
63: {Date: '2021-12-07T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 25.51}
64: {Date: '2021-12-08T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 25.51}
65: {Date: '2021-12-09T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 26.09}
66: {Date: '2021-12-10T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 27.67}
67: {Date: '2021-12-11T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 27.67}
68: {Date: '2021-12-12T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 27.67}
69: {Date: '2021-12-13T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 29.42}
70: {Date: '2021-12-14T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 30.12}
71: {Date: '2021-12-15T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 33.5}
72: {Date: '2021-12-16T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 34.54}
73: {Date: '2021-12-17T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 36}
74: {Date: '2021-12-18T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 36}
75: {Date: '2021-12-19T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 36}
76: {Date: '2021-12-21T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 37.36}
77: {Date: '2021-12-22T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 40.29}
78: {Date: '2021-12-23T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 40.29}
79: {Date: '2021-12-24T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 40.29}
80: {Date: '2021-12-25T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 40.29}
81: {Date: '2021-12-26T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 40.29}
82: {Date: '2021-12-27T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 41.78}
83: {Date: '2021-12-28T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 42.88}
84: {Date: '2021-12-29T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 43.48}
85: {Date: '2021-12-30T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 43.48}
86: {Date: '2021-12-31T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 43.48}
87: {Date: '2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 43.48}
88: {Date: '2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 43.48}
89: {Date: '2022-01-03T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 43.48}
90: {Date: '2022-01-04T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 48.02}
91: {Date: '2022-01-05T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 49.43}
92: {Date: '2022-01-06T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 50.84}
93: {Date: '2022-01-07T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 52.25}
94: {Date: '2022-01-08T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 52.25}
95: {Date: '2022-01-09T00:00:00.000Z', WorkCompletion: 52.25}


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654656/find-missing-day-from-array-of-dates-javascript
```

Comment: The selected answer at that link does appear to handle multiple days missing (between the earliest and latest dates indicated).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find missing day from array of dates javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654656/find-missing-day-from-array-of-dates-javascript)

Comment: @jarmod I tested with all the solutions but didn't work. However, I found a solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651385/fill-missing-dates-in-json-string-with-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
const testing = (data) => {
    const firstDate = data[0].Date;
    const lastDate = data[data.length - 1].Date;
    const dates = [...Array(Date.parse(lastDate) / 86400000 - Date.parse(firstDate) / 86400000 + 1).keys()].map((k) => {
        return (
            new Date(86400000 * k + Date.parse(firstDate))
                .toISOString()
                .slice(0, 10)
                .concat('T00:00:00.000Z')
        );
    });
    let res = [];
    for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        res[i] = {
            Date: dates[i],
            WorkCompletion: dates[i] === data[j].Date ? data[j++].WorkCompletion : data[i - 1].WorkCompletion,
        };
    }
    console.table(res);
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).